# "Toy" Tools for Dependency Parsing?

Tags: computational-linguistics, dependency-grammar

I plan to work with dependency parsing, as an intermediate step in a text understanding problem. I'm also still trying to understand the terminology and methods. Any pointers (or providers) of tools (algorithms, python code, toy-this or that) so that I can implement a parser for purposes of learning about the mechanics of dependency parsing?

I understand that implementing a real parser is a major task. I'm hopeful for just enough information to code a 'toy', to learn more. Yes, I'm hoping I could insert some intermediate "print" statements to dump the state of the parser.

Really simple sentences like "Farmers grow wheat" to start with, then adding a few additional bits "Farmers grow wheat in Ohio", and "Farmers grow wheat in Ohio with water" (which has a few issues to be resolved for understanding).

Comment: For constituency parsing I would have advised pset 2 of  Michael Collins' NLP MOOC: https://class.coursera.org/nlangp-001/assignment/view?assignment_id=5

Comment: I will post Python code that implements a relatively simple dependency parser if that's helpful (implemented this in my college years, back when the dinosaurs roamed the earth).

Comment: Thank you. I will probably learn enough to "rediscover" that I should use an existing parser. That's ok. Finding out what I don't know is all part of the process! Your response appreciated !

Comment: You could use Answer Set Programming, there's an example on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_set_programming#Dependency_parsing

Comment: Please don't edit the body of your question so that it drastically changes its content.

Answer (score 2):

[spaCy.io](http://spacy.io) has a nice high-accuracy lightweight parser.

If you only need English then it is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Try NLTK's dependency parser. Seems to work. Watch for noise in this forum. It is over- moderatoando.NP meaning get your boots ready. Now Ricky has some 'splainibg to do.